# Deleting all Slash Commands

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, command, slash

how to delete all slash commands using discord.js? I'm using 13.5.0 version

```
bot.on('interactionCreate', interaction => {
          if (!interaction.isCommand()) return;
          bot.api.applications(bot.user.id).commands(interaction.commandId).delete();
});
```

I tried to do this, but it's just gives me error: `Uncaught DiscordAPIError: Unknown application command`

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Write a title that **summarizes the specific problem**"_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting slash commands takes up to an hour if done globally, so use the second param, guildid, to delete the slash commands of your bot for a testing server when testing. remove the second param when you want the slash commands to appear globally.

The code would be like so:

```js
bot.application.commands.set([], <GuildId>);
```